# VirtualBox not allowing me to modify IPv4 Network Mask?

Tags: networking, virtualbox, ipv4

I use Oracle VM VirtualBox to run a web server on my machine. I had it set up and working perfectly for a while. For the past few months it's been prompting me to update, and I finally gave in and ran the latest update (4.3.6). And... it's no longer working.

I'm trying to change the host-only adapter setting to what it was before so that it'll work - but for some reason while it's allowing me to edit the IPv4 address, it's not allowing me to change the network mask. I'm trying to change the network mask from the default 255.255.0.0 to 255.255.255.0. It allows me to type it in, and then I hit OK and everything seems fine. But when I go back to the network settings, the mask didn't change. What am I doing wrong?

(Note: I'm running VirtualBox as an administrator.)

Attaching an image of what I'm trying to change -

[image]

Changing only the first works, but if I try modifying the second or both the changes don't "take"...

Answer (score 0):

This may be a known bug; see https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/8796. It doesn't look like that bug is going to be fixed any time soon. Some people have managed to work around it.